# Uso de 'según', 'según conoció' y 'según supo'

Tags: gramática

I'm a bit confused as to the different uses of said phrases.

My understanding of them is -

según - according to.
según conoció (este diario) - This newspaper was informed...
según supo (este diario) - This newspaper discovered...

I can't find any information on this anywhere and I'm not even certain that my translations are correct. They seem to appear regularly in newspaper articles however.

Hopefully someone can enlighten me.

cheers.

Comment: Another way of looking at the second phrase is: *as this newspaper discovered*.  Take a look at a dictionary entry for *según* -- I think your phrases fit well with the standard definitions and usage examples.  E.g. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/según

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems that según can also be translated as 'as', which makes it a lot easier to understand the above. As an aside, My wife is a native speaker and she feels that según conoció and según supo have slightly different meanings. She reckons that conocer is used when the information was offered without solicitation and saber is used to mark a direct investigation. She said it's difficult to explain though and that she could be wrong. Shame there's not much info on it. Thanks again.

Comment: It's because *conocer* and *saber* are different in Spanish even though they both map to *to know* in English.  *As this reporter became aware* vs. *As this reporter established or came to know* might partially capture the nuanced difference in this context.

Comment: In your situation you're going to want to choose an online dictionary and a paper dictionary that you really like using, and spend some time getting comfortable using them.  A good dictionary will give you MULTIPLE definitions of words, colloquialisms, and usage examples.  I personally like Collins and linguee.com as online dictionaries, and the big hard cover Velázquez. I suggest you spend some time in a bookstore in a comfortable chair looking things up and comparing.  Consider weight, font size, binding type and pronunciation system.  Our site has a resources with dictionary info someplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most accurate translation for "según" is the one that you indicated first: "according to".
The second and third sentences are some free/poetical application of the term "according to" and they both translate to: "According to the information obtained by (this newspaper)...".

Personally I find those sentences a bit weird but that's one of the difficulties of Spanish, so many people speaking it! :))